# How can i resolve this content security policy error?

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy

when i run my node index file my getting this error in the browser

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

can any help me how can i resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach to solve this issue is not to send a `Content-Security-Policy` response header if the client requests `/favicon.ico`.

However, depending on your specific use case there might be better solutions, e.g. setting `img-src 'self'` for the file or all static images below the root path.

In all cases you should return a HTTP `404 Not Found` status code if you don't have a `/favicon.ico`.